# Swift: Sharing image to Twitter by deeplinking into the Twitter app

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, deep-linking, sharing

I'm trying to share an image and a caption from an iOS app to Twitter without using the Twitter Kit library. Ideally, it should work exactly like the Spotify sharing I attached to this post. Any thoughts on this?

I scanned through Twitter documentation but I don't see much in there on this topic.

I've also tried using Apple's SLComposeViewController but the issue there is that images are being displayed as URLs instead of images when they appear on Twitter:

```
if let vc = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter) {
                        vc.setInitialText("some caption")
                        vc.add(UIImage(named: "my_image",
                                               in: InternalConstants.bundle,
                                               compatibleWith: nil)!)
                        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
                        nc.present(vc, animated: true)
                    }
```

**Please don't mark this question as a duplicate unless the solution offers instant deep linking like on the gif attached.**

Thank you!

[image: Twitter sharing on Spotify]

Comment: please share your codes and what have you try so far

Comment: @zeytin Updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @KirillKudaev did you get your answer?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini I did. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to hear that! don't forget to mark it as the answer if it was the answer to you :)

Comment: @Kirill, were you actually able to achieve this for twitter?

Answer (score 5):

Spotify is **NOT** sharing ***an image and a caption***! Instead, it shares a link to the site which contains the proper meta data to show the `image`, `title`, `description` and etc. You can achieve this kind of links by reading more about the **[Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me)** and **Rich Link**

In summary, the destination page should contain these in the header:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
```

<sub>Example taken from the ogp.me</sub>

#### Preview of the example on Tweeter

[image: Demo]

---

**Note that** remember some social media and platforms support different meta! Make sure to **TEST** your link in all of your target platforms (WhatsApp, Telegram, Facebook, Tweeter, etc.)

#### Preview of the example on WhatsApp

[image: Demo 2]